# Non-clickable placeholder needed

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor, placeholder, clickable

I am building a site for a client that will *eventually* need button links and need to be clickable.  For now, though, I would just like a placeholder anchor tag for future use, but I DON'T want it to be clickable.  Is there a way to do this?  Below, the 'small red button' is a clickable link, but doesn't go anywhere.  I just don't want to confuse the client when they see the mockup and the link doesn't work.

```
<a href="#" class="small-red-button">What&rsquo;s <strong>New</strong></a>
```

Thanks!  And sorry if this is a newbie question.

EDIT:  It worked like this, as suggested:

```
<a class="small-red-button">What&rsquo;s <strong>New</strong></a>
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I hope the client won't be confused thinking the red should be a clickable link and appears not clickable

Comment: remove href attribute. (href attribute is set, the element defines a source anchor for a link that may be activated by the user to retrieve a Web resource)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the `href` attribute out. It is what makes an anchor element into a link.

Comment: So it should be like this?

    <a class="small-red-button">What&rsquo;s <strong>New</strong></a> 

Maybe I've got something wrong; this didn't change anything.

Comment: Not sure what I was doing wrong, but I DID get this to work!  Fixed!!  Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="small-red-button">What&rsquo;s <strong>New</strong></a>`

it's still a clickable anchor but it as no efect (ie. does't change your adress to www.site.com/#)